# Segmentation fault when jumping to label

Tags: c, gcc, label

Hey the following code is driving me crazy and is giving me a segmentation fault when I run it. Note I am using first class labels here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   static void* array[] = {&&label2, &&label1};
   void* programCount = array;

   goto *programCount++;


   label2: ;
     int b = 100;
     printf("%d\n", b);

   label1: ;
     int b2 = 1000;
     printf("%d\n", b2);
}
```

I can't see why this is happening, it compiles fine...

Comment: This is not standard C.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Agree with Oli. And I doubt than it compiles fine (what about incrementing void pointer??). Do you have warnings turned on?

Comment: im using gcc version 4.7.2, and in the manual for this version it says that support for first class labels has been added, so it should run...

Comment: My evening is now ruined, thank you. No hope left for mankind. If this is what the GCC devs are focusing one, including not warning on `void** -> void*` conversion, what future does this compiler have?

Comment: Why to use a non-portable solution for something that can be done with an array of pointer-to-function?

Comment: @gustafr: Unfortunately, that's a completely valid assignment.  If GCC chose to warn, there would potentially be a lot of false positives.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, and I take **any** amount of false positives over true negatives (caused by mistakes) that are invisible and hidden by the compiler until things break at run-time. But I guess supporting code like this is more important than some incredibly easy static analysis which would detect that you're trying to `goto` an address of a label, rather than the label itself... By it might only be me.

Comment: This is pretty much the ASSIGNED GOTO of older versions of Fortran, which was quite possibly the worst programming construct ever devised.  Why anyone would ever choose to use a construct like this is utterly beyond me.  There are a half dozen good solutions to problems like this and one hideously bad solution.  Congrats on finding the hideously bad one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question refers to a gcc extension, [Labels as Values](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html).

The code from the question compiles fine, although it gives a lot of warnings when compiled with `-Wall -pedantic`. I suppose the issue is with the assignment to the `void*` pointer. The following code works well:

```
static void* array[] = {&&label2,&&label1};

goto *array[0];
```

As @ouah writes, the type of your void pointer is wrong. When you are using `void**`, then the following also works:

```
void** programCount = array;

goto *programCount[0];
// or goto *programCount[1];
```

And, finally, to reflect the code from your question, you can also use

```
void** programCount = array;

goto **(++programCount);
```

to jump to the second label in the array (`label1`). Note that you need to use pre-increment to increment the pointer before evaluating its value.

**Disclaimer:** I am not in favor of using labels or `goto` in C or C++. There are other language elements which provide a more suitable solution to such problems, e.g. as @jweyrich wrote arrays of pointer-to-functions. Since this is non-portable, it should not be used in real life applications (if I was the code reviewer, it would not get through the review ;-) )

Comment: thats true, im just using goto for performace optimisations reasons.

Comment: @user1974753 Worst reason ever.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `programCount`  is not correct, use `void **`:

```
void **programCount = array;
```

then you need to dereference `programCount`  twice like:

```
goto *programCount[0];
```

to jump to the label `label2`, or

```
goto *programCount[1];
```

to jump to the label `label1`.

Here the  `&&` operator is the GNU C [label address operator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html).